# Print values from structure

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

I have structure:

> std::map<std::string, std::vector > someValues;

How can I print all values like:
1, string
2, values from vector?

I have more maps in my c++ project and i need some loops to printf all values.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for what you want.

```
for (const auto& [key, vec] : someValues) {
    std::cout << key << std::endl;
    for (const auto& val : vec) {
        std::cout << "    " << val << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit of explanation (especially the use of structured bindings) might be in order here.